# Visual Studio has stopped working on clicking Go To Definition (F12)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio crashes while pressing F12 (Go To Definition) after fresh installation.
But its working if i log on using different profile on same machine. i tried resetsettings, resetuserdata, resetpkg etc also deleted visual studio folder from %user% folder but issue still persisting

Note: Goto Definition is not working only on type or method which is referred from other assembly or Dotnet framework types(such as Form, Console etc)

Comment: Have you tried resetting the keybinding in tools > options > Environment > Keyboard?

Comment: To find out whether it is keybinding.related or not, mark a definition you want to go to and enter the command `>Edit.GoToDefinition` manually in the Find box of the Standard tool bar (Ctrl+')

Comment: As you suggested i tried but facing same problem. I hope this is not relevant to shortcut key becoz same problem occur even if i initiate via Context Menu also tried installing an Extension for GotoDefinition but no use.